# How to tell if an iPhone app was made with PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, cordova, ipa

I'm not sure if an iPhone app was built with PhoneGap middleware or from scratch. How could I tell this from the .ipa files on my computer? There's not much to it (the app is a shell around a website) apart from an executable and a .nib file which is compiled so I can't open it with Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that .ipa is a .zip file. You should be able to rename the .ipa to .zip, unarchive, and then use binary examination tools (otool, strings, etc.) to determine if the Phonegap-related classes/methods are in the executable.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at it with `otool` now and trying to understand the output, but when I try to use `strings` it just says "malformed object (unknown load command 9)" -- any idea what that means?

Comment: From memory, "otool -o" is what you want to see the symbols in the file (you'll want to unarchive it first). The strings command needs an argument of the file in question (also unarchived) and will show you the ASCII sequences that are found in the file.